# hibernate for child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Quick hibernate question - How can I use Hibernate annotations to define this class as an entity -

```
public class NativeType {
  private long id;    
  private String name;
  private int maxPrecision;
  private byte maxScale;
  private DataStoreProvider provider;
```

linked as a Map Collection in the AbstractDataStoreProvider class -

```
public abstract class AbstractDataStoreProvider implements DataStoreProvider,
  Serializable{

  private Map<String, NativeType> uniqueNativeTypes;
  ..

public interface DataStoreProvider {
```

so I can store this in DB tables like so -

```
**datastore_provider**
provider_id  |  provider_name

**native_type**
native_type_id  |  name  |  max_precision  |  max_scale  |  provider_id
```

I think its me, but I cant navigate the Hibernate specs very easily. New to Java, and newer to JPA + Hibernate. Appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

**Code Sample**

I think you can use the following -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "native_type")
public class NativeType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "native_type_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "max_precision")
    private int maxPrecision;

    @Column(name = "max_scale")
    private byte maxScale;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="provider_id")
    private DataStoreProvider provider; 

    // rest of the class (getter setter etc.)
}
```

**ID Generation**

I am assuming you are auto-generating your database ids, hence I marked it with the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. As for the `strategy`, I specified `AUTO` which is only suitable for local experiments. For production-grade application, you'll have to choose between `SEQUENCE`, `IDENTITY`, and `TABLE`.

**Relation Mapping**

I assumed that you are going to create a `DataStoreProvider` entity too. In that case, you can specify the relation between them as described above.

**Reference**

For further reference, you can consult [this excellent book](http://www.apress.com/9781430219569).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @MD Sayem Ahmed I will give this a shot and share!

Comment: Does the Pro JPA2 reference you shared deal with Hibernate too?

Comment: @BiAct: It discusses JPA, and you can easily use Hibernate as the implementation. Since you tagged this question with `jpa`, I assumed this is what you are using. In order to configure JPA with hibernate properly, you can check out some of [my blog posts](http://codesod.com/category/java/jpa/). One thing though - they only show how to configure it for Java SE environment, but you can extend them pretty easily for web context too.

Comment: How would I indicate this relationship in the parent DataStoreProvider class? Just mark the map uniqueNativeTypes as @OneToMany? Would you mind updating your answer for the DataStoreProvider entity annotations too? Thanks!

Comment: `Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class` - this is the problem. You need to mark `DataStoreProvider` with an `@Entity`. As I said, I assumed you are going to define it as an entity too.

Comment: Still not working - I got a 'Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.dumbledore.datadictionary.AbstractDataStoreProvider.uniqueNativeTyp‌​es[com.dumbledore.datadictionary.NativeType]' trying to define the map for nativetypes in the parent DataStoreProvider with OneToMany annotation

Comment: Sorry I reposted my comment with an edit - I thought its complaining about NativeType being an unmapped class no? DataStoreProvider has the @Entity and Table name annotations on it

Comment: @BiAct: Could you also paste the code for `DataStoreProvider` as well?

Comment: just did - I have no annotations on the interface DataStoreProvider